# What is the exact command to restart a RedHat linux system?

Tags: command-line, reboot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am new in Linux and I want to know the exact command to restart a RedHat linux server 6.3. And it has to start network drivers etc…

I am using VPN to connect to remote machine using VNC.

Can anyone help from the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to wake up a sleeping remote machine with no active network connections?

Answer (score 29):

To restart your machine just use

```
reboot
```

All the services that are configured to start will be started as usual.

Comment: Hi some thing like int0 to init 6... which mode it ll change..?

Comment: Just an addition, you have to be root for this and for restarting everything correctly, the system has to be set up correctly.

Comment: @Michaek IT wont go to different mode. like init1 or some other

Comment: May be: **sudo reboot** is better.

Comment: @shasi on a standard RH installation a normal user does not have the permission to reboot. Then either edit sudoers or get a root shell and reboot.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but assuming you have *root* (or `sudo`) privileges, then `/sbin/reboot` (or `/sbin/shutdown -r now`) will perform a full system reboot.

Comment: i want restart system by remote terminal i have root acces

Comment: Then reboot (or /sbin/shutdown -r now) will perform a full system reboot - even if commanded from SSH

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps to you (provided I got you right). I believe you want to reboot remote linux machine.

Make sure you have root access and then run below command.

```
ssh root@destination_server_to_be_rebooted  reboot
```