# what is the exact command to Restart a redhat linux system via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the exact command to Restart a redhat linux system?](https://superuser.com/questions/466792/what-is-the-exact-command-to-restart-a-redhat-linux-system)

I want to restart the Linux (Redhat server 6.3) System via ssh. I am accessing the remote machine via Putty.

If I give `reboot` command. Will it restart all services or after restarting it'll ask password ?

Can we restart via ssh? Can we access the machine after restarting with out doing anything in the system local terminal.

How can be done restarting?